# Access denied for mysql docker image in bamboo

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, bamboo

I've got this configuration for a MySQL Docker image:

```
mysqldata:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql

mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "8203:3306"
    volumes_from:
      - mysqldata
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes"
      - "MYSQL_USER=root"
```

and I lift it up with `docker-compose up -d mysql`, and I can run commands against the DB in the image, access it without problems, etc.

Then I setup a docker image to be lifted in Bamboo:

[image]

But it fails when running commands against the DB in that image, with the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

From the build logs of the test run I can see that the env variables are applied:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --workdir /data --detach --name mysql-user-service -p 8203:3306 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -e MYSQL_USER=root mysql:5.6
```

But still no success.

Anyone knows how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you connecting from? The host, another container?

Did you give permissions to the user@localhost MySQL user so it has access to the database? That error usually means the user you are connecting with doesn't have access to the db, and you need to grant the permissions.

If you do a `docker ps` you will see the name and the ID of the container you started for MySQL. Take that name or ID and run

```
docker exec -it <name or id> sh
```

That will get you into the container and you can run your MySQL commands to grant access something like this.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost
```

Since you are using compose you can do something like this as well

```
docker-compose run mysql GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost
```

You might also have to create the database of there isn't one already, and you would use the same steps just change the sql that is run

Comment: The problem is that this is happening in an automated test plan in `Bamboo`, so there's no way I can check for the ID of the docker container and then enter it...

Comment: Hmm, have you tried naming the container with --name and then referencing the named container, instead of using the container ID?